# VB6 code to stream video using bosch ptz ip camera

Tags: vb6

Can anyone share the code and which ActiveX control did you used to integrate IP camera in vb6?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very wide scoped question. There are various 3rd party controls that can receive and render motion JPEG/H.264 like the [DTK video capture control](http://www.dtksoft.com/videocap.php).

Alternatively, you can set up a TCP/HTTP connection to receive the video stream, split it into MIME parts and decode and render each in turn.